# Unexpected behavior in Bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

From `man bash`:

```
A simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments
followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and
terminated by a control operator. The first word specifies the
command to be executed, and is passed as argument zero. The
remaining words are passed as arguments to the invoked command.
```

So it's perfectly legal to write:

```
foo=bar echo $foo
```

but it doesn't work as I expect (it prints just a newline). It's quite strange to me since:

```
$ foo=bar printenv
foo=bar
TERM=rxvt-unicode
[...]
```

Could someone please explain me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because variable expansion is done before the command is run. At the time variable expansion happens, `foo` is not set, so it expands to the empty string. The command then runs, setting `foo`.

Comment: Also, note that since foo is set as a prefix to the echo command, it's only set for that command (and not for subsequent commands).  Compare with `foo=bar eval 'echo eval sees $foo'; echo echo sees $foo` (here, since `$foo` is expanded within the `eval` command, the value *will* be substituted there, but not for the next echo command).

Comment: This is an assignment in the child's environment (i.e. `echo` in the original question or `eval` in Gordon's example). Variable assignments in the child's environment do not affect variable values in the parent's. `foo=bar eval 'foo=$foo'; echo $foo` outputs only a newline.

Comment: From `man bash`: "If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell  environment.  Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell  environment.   If  any  of  the assignments attempts to assign a value to a readonly variable, an error occurs, and the command exits with  a  non-zero status."

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `foo=bar` and `echo $foo` on one line, it will not work. You will have to do one of three things.

1. Run them as seperate commands. i.e: `foo=bar` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `echo $foo`
2. Run them on one line, but with a semicolon between the two. ie: `foo=bar; echo $foo`
3. Same as #2, but with double-ampersands. ie: `foo=bar && echo $foo`

The difference between 2 and 3 is that 3 will only execute `echo $foo` if `foo=bar` succeeded.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to work around to the problem. I only was interested on the example I provided.

Comment: +1: Nice set of alternatives though. This might come handy to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foo=bar; echo $foo
       ^
```

Mind the `;` since you're trying to fit two seperate commands on a single line. They don't work together by default.

Comment: See [my other comment](http://superuser.com/questions/203228/unexpected-behavior-in-bash/203237#203237).

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to do it would be:

```
foo=bar sh -c 'echo $foo'
```